# Finding incomplete solutions of second order ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, nonlinear-system

For a smooth, 1-periodic, positive function $c:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ consider the following second order ODE system for the curve $\gamma(t)= (x(t),y(t),z(t)):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ (note that I will denote the derivative of $c$ by a prime and the derivatives of the curve components $x,y,z$  by dots).

\begin{align}
(i) \hspace{15mm} \ddot{x}(t)+ \frac{c'(z(t))}{c(z(t))}~ \dot{x}(t)\dot{z}(t)=0 \\
(ii) \hspace{14mm} \ddot{y}(t) +\frac{c'(z(t))}{c(z(t)))}~\dot{y}(t)\dot{z}(t)=0 \\
(iii) \hspace{16mm} \ddot{z}(t)-c'(z(t)) ~ \dot{x}(t)\dot{y}(t)=0
\end{align}

**My question:** I'm interested in finding a function $c$ as described above such that the system has "incomplete" solutions, i.e. solutions $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ which are not defined for all times $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Or alternatively I want to show that for all $c$ as above there are no incomplete solutions.

**Background:** the background to this problem is a geometric one: I have a family of metrics $\{g_c\}$ given on $\mathbb{R}^3$ (where $c$ is as described above) and I'm asking myself if all those metrics are geodasically complete. Solving the geodesic equation for those metrics gives the above system of ODEs.

Answer (score 4):

The equation system has the following first integrals:
$$c(z)^2\left(\dot x^2+\dot y^2\right)=I_1=const$$
$$c(z)\left(y\dot x-x\dot y\right)=I_2=const$$
If $c_{MIN}<c(z)<c_{MAX}$, then $\dot x$ and $\dot y$ are bounded:
$$|\dot x|<\frac{\sqrt{I_1}}{c_{MIN}}$$
$$|\dot y|<\frac{\sqrt{I_1}}{c_{MIN}}$$
Assuming that $c'(z)$ is a bounded smooth function, $\ddot z(t)$ is also bounded. This means that there are no singular solutions (such that $x$, $y$ or $z$ reach infinity for finite $t$). Also, [existence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_existence_theorem) guarantees existence of solution to the initial value problem in the neighborhood of every $t=t_0$, so there are no incomplete solutions.

Comment: @user450093: to find $I_1$: multiply equation (i) by $\dot x$, (ii) by $\dot y$, and add them. To find $I_2$: multiply equation (i) by $y$, (ii) by $x$, and subtract the latter from the former. However, such procedure does not work with equation (iii).

Comment: This is already really helpful! But to me it is not clear yet how you conclude that all solutions are complete from the fact that $\dot{x}$,$\dot{y}$ and $\ddot{z}$ are bounded (especially I don't see how the boundedness of $\ddot{z}$ is used).

Comment: The idea is that if a solution cannot be extended beyond $t=t_0$, then $x(t_0)$ or $y(t_0)$ or $z(t_0)$ is infinite. This is impossible because $x(t_0)=\infty$ means that $\dot x(t_0) = \infty$, so $|\dot x|$ must be unbounded. Similarly,  $z(t_0)=\infty$ means that $\ddot z(t_0)=\infty$.

Comment: However, I agree that my proof is not very strict, it does not rule out other types of singularities, for example $\dot x(t)=\sin{(1/(t-t_0))}$.